# Insert New Row In GridView Footer At Button Click at Run Time

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I just want to insert A new row in gridView Footer On button click, which is out side Of gridview. every time user click On button There is New row will be inserted In gridview footer for data entry with text box. GridView data row shows the data from database and in  footer row which contain text box For new  entry. user can add more than one Footer row with text box on by clicking on the button. 
Please help me...
 Thanks...

Comment: you capitalization and lack of formatting makes this post very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a similar situation, however we were adding rows dynamically to the body of the table. No reason a similar approach wouldn't work. Note that if you need to submit this data back to the server then some additional functionality needs to be implemented.

Some code is below.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var newRow = $('table tfoot').First('.Row').clone();  // If you need to insert dynamically you can create the elements in code
    $('table tfoot').append(newRow);    
});
```